# Is that efficient way of using require

Tags: php, html

So basically the question when I'm making a website is that efficient way of doing to use 3 require PHP functions to call some of my static elements :

1. first one to my navbar and links to css stylesheets
2. second on the bottom of the page for footer
3. the third one to file where I have links to my scripts

Do you use other methods than require or include or this is a good way of doing this

Comment: efficient enough :) you should use `include` because `require` will halt script if it doesn't find a file and include will only raise a warning.

Comment: It is quite applicable for very small projects, in larger projects it is better to think about template engines.

Answer (score 1):

The include and require statements are identical, except upon failure:

- **require** will produce a fatal error `E_COMPILE_ERROR` and stop the
  script.
- **include** will only produce a warning `E_WARNING` and the script will continue.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using autoloader as described here
[Using php Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)
and wrap your functionality using Classes
it will produce much cleaner and easier to maintain php code,
even for small projects as it leaves options for using third party extensions such as Facebook or Paypal later on.

Try to differentiate between Output, Input and functionality
it doesn't have to resemble MVC but it's a good practice.